# Visual C++ Byte *

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I just switched from Dev C++ to Visual C++ and I'm getting an error in my code that I wasn't getting when using Dev C++. The error is:

```
------ Build started: Project: badman_flex, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
main.cpp
c:\documents and settings\administrator\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\badman_flex\badman_flex\main.cpp(49): error C2664: 'RegSetValueExA' : cannot convert    parameter 5 from 'char *' to 'const BYTE *'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or    function-style cast
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The code around that line is:

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regPath, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);  
RegQueryValueEx(hKey,"Userinit", 0, 0, (BYTE*)buff, &dwBufSize);

if(!strstr(buff, "myapp.exe")) {  

char *filepath = strcat(windowsDir, filename);
char *newRegValue = strcat(buff, filepath);
RegSetValueEx(hKey, "Userinit", 0, REG_SZ, newRegValue, strlen(newRegValue));
```

What is a byte and why is VC++ causing an error?

Thanks

**Edit** I typecast and it worked :D

Comment: 'What is a byte' epic.

Comment: A BYTE is a 8-bit quantity also known as unsigned char. It is the most basic addressable type in most operating system.

Comment: @cpx: Actually, a byte is the smallest addressable piece of memory. It needn't be 8bit, although a platform needs to have at least 8bit in a byte to conform to the C and C++ standards.

Comment: @fazo: to be fair, the question wasn't "what is a byte", rather "what is a BYTE (as defined by VC++)". Can you blame someone for not assuming the trivial when it comes to Microsoft products? :P

Answer (score 1):

The RegSetValueEx() API accepts different kind of data to be written to the registry.  Its 5th argument is a pointer to that data, declared as BYTE*.  You are passing it a char*, wrong type.  Note that you are doing it right a few lines back in the RegQueryValueEx() call.  Fix:

```
 RegSetValueEx(hKey, "Userinit", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)newRegValue, strlen(newRegValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

from windef.h

`typedef unsigned char       BYTE;`

So either include windef.h or define this yourself